# Polars: Concatenating column names depending on value

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I have a table as follows:

```
    a   b   c   d   e
    0   1   0   1   0
    1   0   0   0   0
```

I want to create a column `RESULT` that is a concatenation of column names only if the row has a value of `1`.

```
    a   b   c   d   e    RESULT
    0   1   0   1   0    bd   
    1   0   0   0   0    a
```

Whats the most efficient way of doing this with polars?

I can do this via a `map_elements`, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way.

Comment: What have you tried? Why are you not satisfied with your approach? Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It also helps if you provide the code used to generate the example dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach is usually to use `when/then` and loop over `.columns`

In this case you want the column name or an empty string.

You can pass this directly to [`.concat_str()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.concat_str.html) to combine the result.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
   'a': [0, 1], 'b': [1, 0], 'c': [0, 0], 'd': [1, 0], 'e': [0, 0]
})
```

```py
df.with_columns(RESULT =
   pl.concat_str(
      pl.when(pl.col(col) == 1).then(pl.lit(col)).fill_null("")
      for col in df.columns
   )
)
```

```
shape: (2, 6)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ d   ┆ e   ┆ RESULT │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str    │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪════════╡
│ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ bd     │
│ 1   ┆ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ a      │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴────────┘
```